# Render layout (Jade) by an Ajax "POST" request

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express, pug

well, i have my generic ajax.

```
export function urlDynamic(obj) {

    $.ajax({
        url: obj.url,
        type: 'post',
        data: obj.jade,
        dataType: 'JSON'
    }).done(function (ajaxReturn) {
        console.log(ajaxReturn, obj);
        if (ajaxReturn.hasOwnProperty('response')) {
            if (ajaxReturn.response.status === 'success') {
                console.log(ajaxReturn.response.data);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

and I want to render my new page by the ajax request

```
    module.exports = function (app) {
    app.post('/montit', function (req, res) { //faz o requerimento da rota "/" através do metodo GET
        //console.log('teste rota');
        //res.send('GET request to the homepage');
        console.log('POSTTTTTT');
        app.render('indexMonitoramento', {title: 'Main',
            bodyClass: 'telaLogin'
        }); //responde, Renderiza o layout da pagina
    });
};
```

my console.log show's me the "POSTTTTT" in console, but he dosen't render my layout!

Comment: Why would it render your layout? The AJAX request is expecting JSON and you're sending HTML.

Comment: i'm just sending the url because this ajax gonna be a generic ajax for the prohject, i want to render all the layout in jade file by ajax post request

Comment: @BenFortune i'm just want to send a request via post from ajax to render my layout, but I do not have any idea on how i do this

Answer (score 0):

You have to change according to with this.I hope it will work now

[View is not change after render .pug file from express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42857413/view-is-not-change-after-render-pug-file-from-express/42861479#42861479)

Comment: Rahul sharing only a link doesn't help much. When you answer a question please include the key parts of the content with the link. So if link doesn't work in future peaople still can use your answer.