# View is not change after render .pug file from express

Tags: javascript, express, pug

I have some problem that the html view is not change after render the pug file,after getting the server response.

The code is following

```
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
 app.set("views", require('path').join(__dirname, "views"));

app.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
console.log(req.body);
checkExistanceOfuser(req.body.username, req.body.password, function(err, flag, data) {
    console.log(err);
    if (err) {
        res.send({
            err: 'SOME_DATABASE_ERROR'
        })
    } else {
        if (flag) {

            req.session.user = data;

            /*res.send({
                success: true,
                message: 'Login Success'
            })*/

            res.render('welcome', { name: data.name });
        } else {
            /*res.send({
                success: false,
                message: 'Invalid Credentials'
            });*/
            res.render('login', { error: 'Invalid Credentials' });
        }
    }
})
```

But i check in network section from browser.The API response (preview) is fine.

Comment: Is the problem that the page isn't rendering? Which page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you are calling `/login` route it's a post call and probably you are using ajax post call for doing so. 
Now when you are calling the `/login` route its rendering the `pug` file
but its not actually effecting the browser DOM. So what you need to do is this

create a new route like this

```
  app.get('/login-success', function(req, res, next) {
        if (req.session && req.session.user) {
            res.render('welcome', { name: req.session.user.name });
        } else {
        res.redirect('/');
        }
  });
```

and modify the login function like this

```
   app.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
      console.log(req.body);
      checkExistanceOfuser(req.body.username, req.body.password, function(err, flag, data) {
      console.log(err);
      if (err) {
         res.send({
            err: 'SOME_DATABASE_ERROR'
         })
      } else {
            if (flag) {

                req.session.user = data;

                res.send({
                    success: true,
                    message: 'Login Success'
                });
             } else {
                res.send({
                success: false,
                message: 'Invalid Credentials'
                });
             }
          }
      })
  });
```

in ajax call use this

```
function login(){
  $.post("http://localhost:8000/login",
  {
    username:document.getElementById("name").value,
    password:document.getElementById("password").value,
  },
  function(data, status){
     if(data.success){
      window.location = "http://localhost:8000/login-success"
     }
  });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

You're rendering `views/login`, but you've already specified that the view folder is `views`. Just render `login`.